# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: ao executar migration no SQLITE com Yii2

Tags: sqlite3, yii2

Estou usando o yii2 para um pequeno projeto, estou usando o sqlite para persistir os dados. E a ai que esta ocorrendo o problema.
Qualquer tabela que eu crie no sqlite o yii2 não reconhece, nem pelo usando o GII para criar as models.
Interessante é que ele conecta no banco corretamente. Criei a tabela com uma migration.

O PDO para sqlite esta ativo.

Arquivo de configuração do yii:

```
 return [
          'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
          'dsn'=>'sqlite:portaltransporte.db',
          'username' => '',
          'password' => '',
          'charset' => 'utf8',

          // Schema cache options (for production environment)
         //'enableSchemaCache' => true,
        //'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
       //'schemaCache' => 'cache',
    ];
```

Código da migration:

```
<?php

  use yii\db\Migration;
  use yii\db\Schema;    
   class m181207_172303_tabela_contrato extends Migration
   {
      /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
      public function safeUp()
      {
         $this->createTable('contrato',[
            'id'    =>Schema::TYPE_PK,
            'url'   =>Schema::TYPE_STRING .'NOT NULL',
            'post'  =>Schema::TYPE_STRING,
            'get'   =>Schema::TYPE_STRING,
            'put'   =>Schema::TYPE_STRING,
            'base'  =>Schema::TYPE_STRING,  
          ]);

      }

      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
       public function safeDown()
       {
          echo "m181207_172303_tabela_contrato cannot be reverted.\n";
          $this->dropTable('contrato');
          return false;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse problema acontece quando não referenciamos o caminho adequadamente.
Neste caso só foi preciso colocar a seguinte referencia no arquivo de configuração

```
return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn'=>'sqlite:@app/db/portal.db',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
       ];
```

E o problema foi resolvido.